# Using Google Tag Manager on a Single Page Application by using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I'm implementing `Google Tag Manager` on my `ReactJS` website.

For that, I get the following instructions from `Google` docs:

Reference: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart

Copy the following JavaScript and paste it as close to the opening  tag as possible on every page of your website, replacing `GTM-XXXX` with your container ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Copy the following snippet and paste it immediately after the opening  tag on every page of your website, replacing GTM-XXXX with your container ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

My problem is that my `ReactJS` websites has many pages that change without refreshing the browser. I mean, it is a `Single Page App` (`SPA`) which loads just once and after that the user can browse around the pages of that `SPA` without refreshing the browser.

I want to track just one page: `/thank-you`.

What would be the best way to achieve this. I have investigated a lot but didn't find any way to do this with plain `Javascript`.

Any code snippet would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use History Change trigger to track SPA. Here's the basic [description](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en&dark=0) at GTM help pages. This allows GTM to capture location updates of React Application.

Yet you might find useful some guides like [this](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/#gref)

Comment: Дмитро thanks. The point here is that I don't own the Google account where the tag manager config was created. Then I just was provided (by a third party person) the two blocks of code I pasted on my post above. Then, due to the given circumstances, am I forced to ask that third party person to follow (on his Google account) the steps indicated on your doc reference: 1. Click Triggers and then New | 2. Click Trigger Configuration and choose the History Change trigger type?. Also, remember that I want to track just one page: `/thank-you`. Thanks!

Comment: Google Tag Manager doesn't track the pages itself. It's used to `fire` some tracking tags meaning calling some JS codes that send tracking data to the systems like google analytics. In order to track /thank_you page on SPA site wtih let's sat Google Analytics and GTM one needs to create a "Google Analytics pageview" tag and set it to fire on History Change trigger.